# What is the smallest execution unit in ksh? Is it a command?

Tags: ksh

I'd like to find out if there are different kinds of "statements" in ksh. For instance, in C, there are preprocessor statement, expression, etc.

Comment: The man page is quite thorough and seems to address your question quite well. Is there something you're after that is not covered there?

Comment: I just wanted to view the ksh grammar in similar terms as other programming languages.

There seems to two kinds of statements that are executable in ksh: variable assignments and commands.